# Ruby: Calling variable from array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables

How do I call a variable from an array? Trying to make this:

```
hello_world = "Hey"
array = [ '#{hello_world} ho' ]
array.each do |a|
  puts a
end
```

say `["Hey ho"]` instead of `["\#{hello_world} ho"]`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as below -

```
hello_world = "Hey"
array = [ "#{hello_world} ho" ]
array # => ["Hey ho"]
array.each do |a|
  p a
end
# >> "Hey ho"
```

Single-quoted strings  disabling interpolation, but double-quote strings allow interpolation.

*Remember* - [Interpolation may be disabled](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) by escaping the `“#”` character or using *single-quote strings*:

```
'#{1 + 1}' #=> "\#{1 + 1}"
```